# Use variables in Array mapping reactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I want to make few tables from an Array using dropdown list. List will be Daily, weekly, Monthly, yearly.

I have written the code. Below is the sample array.

```
 var allPoints = records.map(
      (
        { id, sector_name, f_day_lot1, f_day_lot2, f_day_lot3, f_day_lot4 }
      ) => (
          { id, sector_name, f_day_lot1, f_day_lot2, f_day_lot3, f_day_lot4 }
        )
    );
```

The thing is I want to change the above `day` to `weekly, monthly or yearly` depends on the dropdown.
I can write same code for multiple times changing `day` to `weekly, monthly or yearly`. But then it will be alot of code. So, is there any other better way to do.

Or how to make day as a variable and change value depending upon menu.

Comment: Do you have `day ` state known everytime?

Comment: i need to make it dynamic. so it can be a variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the exact data structure of your records. But I think you can use a dynamic key name:

```js
function getPoints(records, dropdownValue) {
  return records.map((item) => {
    let mapedItem = {};
    for (const key in item) {
      if (key.indexOf(`${dropdownValue}_lot`) !== -1) {
        mapedItem[key] = item[key];
      }
    }
    mapedItem["id"] = item["id"];
    mapedItem["sector_name"] = item["sector_name"];
    return mapedItem;
  });
}
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    sector_name: 2,
    f_day_lot1: "f_day_lot1",
    f_day_lot2: "f_day_lot2",
    f_day_lot3: "f_day_lot3",
    f_day_lot4: "f_day_lot4",
    f_month_lot1: "f_month_lot1",
    f_month_lot2: "f_month_lot2",
    f_month_lot3: "f_month_lot3",
    f_month_lot4: "f_month_lot4",
    f_week_lot1: "f_week_lot1",
    f_week_lot2: "f_week_lot2",
    f_week_lot3: "f_week_lot3",
    f_week_lot4: "f_week_lot4"
  }
];
console.log(getPoints(data, "day"));
console.log(getPoints(data, "week"));
console.log(getPoints(data, "month"));
```